# echo alert() in php show everything in the string. octobercms plugin

Tags: javascript, php, plugins, octobercms

I'm having issue when echoing alert() in php. It show everything in the string.

```html
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Thank you for your enquiry, we will contact you as soon as possible, have a nice day!');</script>";
```

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mzArN.png)

Comment: Please specify expected behaviour. `echo` is a function which prints text, if you want to print text from your `alert(...)` then you need to pass just this text without script tag.

Comment: @validname expected behavior is just to show the string in the alert() which is "Thank you for your enquiry, we will contact you as soon as possible, have a nice day!". I had try to pass it without the script tag but it still show everything but without the script tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: I fixed it by removing everything. and just echo the message directly without the alert(). I'm not sure why it behave like this because this is my custom plugin. I will update if I found the source of this behavior. Thank you for all the replies.

```html
echo 'Email Successfully Sent. We will reply soon!';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript code between ending and starting php tags like below,

```
    ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
alert('Thank you for your enquiry, we will contact you as soon as possible, have a nice day!');
</script>
<?php
// rest of the php code will go here.
?>
```

OR try this please,

```html
<?php
echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
echo 'alert("Thank you for your enquiry, we will contact you as soon as possible, have a nice day!");';
echo '</script>';
?>
```